# What happens if a mechanic puts no oil in your car during oil change and the engine picks up oil sludge

Tags: engine

I went to Jiffy Lube 10/3/2016 and had to take it right back on 10/10/2016. I took a trip on 10/7/2016 about 200 miles. My oil light came on, the car smelled as if it was burning once I arrived to my location. The very next day, I didn't drive it until I checked the oil ( there was no oil on the dipstick) I added oil into the car before getting back on the road to return home. I returned home and went to Jiffy Lube explaining what I observed. The manager checked my oil and said that everything was tight but I was right, there was no oil in my car. The manager redid the oil change and gave me a complimentary oil change for the next time. I thought everything was fine until 10/28/16. My engine started making noise and it blew as I was driving. I towed it to the dealership who is saying the cause of the engine blowing was because of oil sludge. My question is if sludge sits in the bottom of the oil pan, if oil was properly put in my car, Would my engine have picked up the sludge?

Pllllllleasssee help.

Comment: It can't pick up sludge from your oil sump if that's what you mean. There's an oil filter that prevents big particles from getting into your engine, and there's a oil strainer that prevents debris and sludge from going into the filter. In the worst case, excessive sludge might constrict oil flow. A lack of oil can, or will, cause serious damage to your engine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the engine was run dry, whatever oil was in there would cook - causing coke (oil cooked to a charcoal consistency) and would also sludge (cooked to a dry tar consistency).  I would take the dealer report back to the oil change place and ask them to cover all repairs necessary since it was likely caused by their negligence.